# Add @reply autocomplete when commenting on the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, comment-replies

When commenting, having an autocomplete when you want to @reply to a user would be wonderful (similar to the one available on the desktop site). Normally when I'm on mobile site, I can copy/paste the username, remove the spaces, and I move on with life. But without copy/paste available within the app, the complex or unicode names are nearly impossible to use @reply.

Comment: Note that copying is possible in posts, but not of any other text (e.g., comments, usernames, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is really hard to type the username in comment box in Stack Exchange app.  However showing username in a auto-complete dropdown menu is good for web-view whereas in app it may not look good(because no-where in app they used auto-complete dropdown).

Here is simple free-hand sketch of its look

[image]

Instead can we have add **Reply** option within ***Comment Options***(to show difference between app and web) like this

[image]

Once they select **Reply**, then as usual we can move to the comment box showing `@Arbaz Abid` therefore we can type the reply comment back easily.

Comment: Looks like your suggestion made it into v1.0.35! I'd still love to see a auto complete drop down like in the Twitter/Facebook/Trello/Gmail/etc.

Comment: @StevenV Is the feature still present? I cannot see it.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It still appears for me in v1.0.68 but in a slightly different spot. It's been moved to the action bar at the top of the screen. The icon is an curved arrow pointing to the left next to the upvote button.

Comment: @StevenV nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer required, since when tapping existing comment, we now have a Reply icon:

> [image]

Tapping it will automatically start a new comment, and put the comment's author name in a reply-format:

> [image]

So the need for autocomplete is nullified.