# Revisions list in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, revisions-list

I find revisions a really useful way to see full edit history of every post in Stack Exchange.

Can we please have it on the iOS app too? It will also let us see original time of the post submission which is missing, currently showing only last edit time.

Comment: Please tell me there's a suggestion like this for the Android app. Otherwise... I'll post it. :P

Comment: @hichris123 looks like you have a green light to post the request! :-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228440/237685. Done. :P

Comment: I think this feature is really necessary for the more moderating users (probably the ones who are like us now testing the alpha)

Comment: @Arie, you got my hopes up when I saw you'd edited this ;)

Comment: @mhlester in case you missed it... **they did it**! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version of this is available in the beta channel.  Tapping on "Edited ... Apr 5 at 23:01" (or equivalent) will take you to a screen like this:

> [image: Revisions list with two revisions]

Tapping an individual revision will get you something that looks like this:

> [image: Single revision showing title, tag, and body edits]

I've still got to polish it up a bit and will probably add a side-by-side view but not markdown (because the API does not yet support it).  The comparison is running client side so there may be differences in the highlighted changes for performance reasons.

And in case you're wondering, [deuterium's nucleus is a boson, the atom is a fermion, the molecule is a boson](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/153755), and I apparently should have been paying better attention in PHY 361 because I had no idea that bosons or fermions were composed of other particles.

Comment: Wow, better than I've expected! Awesome job. By the way, didn't you use to have a cute toddler as your avatar?

Comment: Yeah, but the perspective wasn't good for vulcan ears.  In chat his face is like 4px total.

Comment: Any chance you switch over to the android team for a short while to add this feature in there as well? ;)

Comment: Not available in Android app. I wonder why it is not there for Android app.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ The two apps were maintained relatively independently, so feature requests like this were implemented inconsistently between the two apps.  For iOS, it was just that I had time to kill, it was an interesting project, and it was a good use-case for the exciting new Swift programing language.

Comment: @BrianNickel kill it? Do you mean kill the iOS app? Why? Ah doesn't matter, as long as Android app is alive ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is another one of the three reasons I still have for exiting the app to the mobile site, but it's a tricky one to implement. I've made a pretty ambitious first stab at a mockup:

1. Access through the EllipsiSideways.

   > [image]
2. New window slides open, with list of revisions. Actual implementation maybe shouldn't attribute everything to me. Open to debate though.

   > [image]
3. Tapping one brings up that particular revision:

   > [image]

It's a lot of work, and a lot of new pages. Working through this, I can understand why this hasn't been done yet. Hopefully this workflow is a good start for the conversation though, as it's a valuable tool to have.

Comment: Nice, though I believe they already got something planned somewhere. :-)

Comment: Oh yeah?! Cool! Where did you hear that?

Comment: Just a hunch. 

Comment: This, reputation, and answer sorting are the three things I routinely have to exit the app for