# Add the revision history to the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, revisions-list

Basically this suggestion for the Android app: [Revisions list in iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228437/revisions-list-in-ios-app)

Many times I'll see that a post has been edited on the Android app. I'll want to see exactly what was edited, and the Android app doesn't show this. Can the revision history be added to the Android app?

Comment: The feature is still not available as of 2018, August.

Comment: The feature is still not available as of 2019, August.

Answer (score 3):

Since Google Chrome become the backend for the Webview (which the app already uses for opening links), an alternative to showing the revision history in the app would be to add a link to the revision history, which would open in a Webview. I tested out opening a link to a revision history: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274522/270345

Comment: AFAIK, the in-app browser only works if you have [Chrome installed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262151/open-beta-testing-of-the-stack-exchange-android-app) "*Brings in the Chrome Custom Tabs API which gives much faster access to loading external links from the app. Note that this is only supported on Chrome 45 and above right now*".

Comment: @AndrewT. it should be possible to provide a "beta test" only for those having Chrome installed. ;-)