# Moving from the revision to the post of said revision

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

On the app, when you click a revision on another post like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/135/revisions), in the main site I could go to the post just clicking the "Return to question/answer", but there seems to be no way to achieve the same effect within the app. Can we add a path to go from the revision history to the post?

Comment: Isn't there a "back" icon on top (e.g. I see one [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdCHX.jpg))? I would expect it to get you back to the question. If that's the case, can't see any need to add another button doing the same.

Comment: @ShadowWizard if you tap that bottom, after clicking the "this" link in my post, it will take you back to this question, not the post the review history is about.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's kind of rare edge case, so still not sure it's worth the efforts of adding a whole new button. Guess we'll let Brian decide. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard if anything, it kind of troubled/confused me for a while, since I was expecting the same behavior as the main site.

Comment: Well, since this is essentially a "back" button, the behavior is the same: going back to the previous page. The app simply "miss" lots of buttons and got different overall design, due to the smaller screen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard btw, it's the same behavior in android?

Comment: Don't get me started.... android app has no revisions at all. [It was asked to add them of course](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228440/add-the-revision-history-to-the-android-app), but with nobody working on the app, it will never happen. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard perhaps should make a request to move android-app development into open-source.

Comment: @alexolut haha, lol.... yeah, we should. :-)