# Number instead of title when looking revisions via direct link

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, revisions-list

Recently asked [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289867/339911) helps me to find a bug. If I open revisions via direct link as in mentioned question, then top bar contains a number (question id):

> [image: id]

When revisions is opened from the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/339911) itself, then top bar contains a title of the question:

> [image: title]

- App Version: 1.6.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.3.

The problem was simply one of laziness.  If you're coming from a question or an answer, we can get you a good title from the post you're coming from.  If you're coming from `/posts/135/revisions` we just have a number.

I just needed to make a request to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/posts/135` to get the relevant bits.

Comment: According to TestFlight you missed 1.6.3.3. All your recent posts about fixes should refer to 1.6.3.4.