# Viewing revisions on mobile

Tags: feature-request, edits, android-app, revisions-list

Could this feature be implemented?  I don't see what the point of being able to edit, and being able to see that a question has been edited but not be able to see past edits.

Or is it supposed to work that way and I'm having a bug/being an idiot that's trying to view edit history the wrong way?

Comment: Actually it's really impossible to view the revision list in the android app.

Comment: Is that also true of the IOS app?

Comment: @nicael OP here meant to ask if iOS app has revisions, and [yes it does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228437/revisions-list-in-ios-app). :)