# Links in iOS app revision page are not clickable

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, revisions-list

When viewing a specific revision of a post in the iOS app, clicking links in the contents has no effect.

Even long tapping then choosing Open is not working and is silently ignored.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: The android app seems to be missing that functionality at all: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251307/viewing-revisions-on-mobile that could explain the poor support for certain features?

Comment: @rene looks like the android app got into some sort of "deep freeze", no idea why - they only fix urgent bugs, while iOS app got a bunch of devs working on "extra" features as well. Dunno the reason, but from what I see that's the current situation. Just compare [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+status-completed+feature-request?sort=active&pageSize=50) with [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app+status-completed+feature-request?sort=active&pageSize=50) - point proven beyond any doubt.

Comment: Maybe they are working on the Windows Phone version instead?

Comment: @rene highly doubt it, the market share of Windows Phone is just going down, so can't see any real reason for Stack Exchange to spend lots of resources on this. More likely reason is that they are satisfied with the current status of the android app, and see no reason to keep improving it.

Comment: Android is still very much active but has been focussing on its own things: tablet, material design, markdown toolbar, **device-specific bugs**.  Until recently, there were two of us on iOS too so that alone was enough for me to be able to spend a few weeks on a client-side diff function in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  I had just never bothered setting things up.  I've also added MathJax and prettify support to match the web.