# How to view edit history of a question is Stack Exchange Android App

Tags: discussion, edits, android-app

I have been using Stack Exchange(desktop) for more than 4 years and I know all the options in the website. But now installed the Android App of our SE and viewed a question of Webmaster and I can able to see the text 'Edited' in the question asked by the questioner but when I tried click the Edited button nothing is working.

Could only please help me to access the edit history of question or answer in App?

Note: I'm not able to upload my screenshot for this question and I will ask a separate question regarding this one :-P

Additional Note: In case if this has been asked already kindly redirect me to that question instead of down voting ;-)

Comment: So it means as of now we don't have option to see revision history in App. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, not in the Android-app. It is available in [iOS-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228437/)

Comment: @Arulkumar ok. I don't have Iphone. Let me wait for SE to update the app. Thanks.