# some praise for the developers

Tags: discussion, review, ios-app

I have been testing the alpha iOS Stack Exchange app for about a week now, and I love it! You guys did an amazing job, which is not surprising considering the massive amounts of knowledgeable people who use this site. Nice work fellas.

Comment: Regarding comments you can't post comments on other users posts until  you have 50 reputation points, so I believe that's not part of the bug.

Comment: I wasn't trying to comment, I was clicking a link that someone had added into their comment. When I clicked it it popped up the menu for either up voting or going to their profile. Just as if I had clicked on the comment.

Comment: As far as the duplicate goes. I found it already (see edit 2). I will erase that part of my question.

Comment: I just was able to click the link in Martijn's comment. I don't know why that one i tried before didn't work. I'll edit the comment to be just praise for the developers. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: links in comments are extraordinarily hard to tap. I often have to try 2 or 3 times

Comment: It was only one word, so that's probably why. How do you even post links in comments?

Comment: with `[text](url)`. Click the `help` link to the right when composing a comment (on desktop, not in app)

Comment: FYI: I didn't actually mark this as a duplicate, but it had three existing duplicate votes. The way you've edited the question, while very friendly, doesn't seek input and discussion from the community - which is the real reason I selected.

Comment: Maybe posting this as an answer [over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228422/stack-exchange-ios-app-nearing-beta) would be more appropriate

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure but in the email I got with the download link said to post any bug reports or praise. This actually did start off with some bug reporting but eventually edited down to nothing. Oh well.

Comment: yeah, no worries!