# Are questions about the Stack Exchange phone apps on topic for Meta.SE?

Tags: discussion, meta, android-app, scope, ios-app

Where should Meta questions relating the Android/iOS apps be asked? Meta Stack Exchange? Do they need any other attention than adding the appropriate [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) or [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) tags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack Exchange iOS app nearing beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228422/stack-exchange-ios-app-nearing-beta) and [Help us test the alpha version of our Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200)

Comment: The applications *point to Meta.SE* in their help documentation, mentioning the specific tags. So yes, such questions should be asked here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work on the iOS app and I found this question because it is on MSE and tagged with [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app), so yep.  It's the best way to let us know about bugs, feature requests, etc.

We also look at app reviews but they're one directional (at least for iOS) so there's less we can do for you there.

Answer (score 4):

Issues with the mobile applications affect more than one Stack Exchange site and therefore belong here on MSE.

Both blog posts that introduced the android and ios applications request that questions and feature requests be posted on MSE with the appropriate [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) or [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) tags.

[Android App post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/) - "Let us know how we’re doing" section.

[iOS App post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/) - "What about feature [...]?" section.

Answer (score 3):

If they are about the operation of the applications then they are on topic here.

Your question will get the appropriate attention by using the correct tags.