# Comment autocomplete @reply in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, ios-app, comment-replies

I could have sworn this was submitted already, but can't find it.

Comment replies don't autocomplete in the iOS app. Can we either add that, and/or better still, a reply button from the comment popup menu?

[image: comment reply]

When selecting a comment and tapping *Reply*, the comment field is opened with `@user` pre-filled. If the comment field is *already* open, `@user` is inserted at the caret.

Comment: Nope; there is one [for the Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197985/add-reply-autocomplete-when-commenting-on-the-android-app), but you're the first to request it for iOS, it appears. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have added a comment reply feature in version **0.1.65.**

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: daaaaang, that was fast. thanks! (and take that, android app!)

Comment: @mhlester :( Soon.

Comment: Arie, I'd added a little to this request just before you status-completed it. Should I move it to a new feature request? It's the part about inserting the @user text if the comment field is already open

Comment: I do not see this feature in version 1.0.0 which I downloaded from the App Store today. Can you help me figure out what is going on? @mhlester was telling me the feature existed...

Comment: This feature has disappeared from beta 1.0.0.70 as well

Comment: Sorry, the feature was never planned for appstore version 1.0 (it was developed too late). It was also probably taken out recently because of some issues with it.

Comment: well it's back in '71 anyway. i hear changes are afoot, so i'll go ahead and accept this and let you make your changes internally. thanks!