# Best way to upgrade beta version of iOS app to apple store version?

Tags: support, ios-app

Now that the official version is released, those of us in the beta, should we delete the other app and download the app store version, or is there a more elegant update procedure?

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is the latest version, the update process is... Don't update. It'll be a downgrade

As [Ben said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228422/stack-exchange-ios-app-nearing-beta) when the app was submitted for review,

> Well, we intend to keep the alpha test group around, except now we're considering it the "beta channel". It's still important to us, particularly since the update cycle through the AppStore is slow. We'll still roll out updates in the same way that we have been. We will also from time ask for targeted feedback on specific features.

There's already a difference between the two. The <del>alpha</del> beta has comment replies, while the release version does not.

[Comment autocomplete @reply in iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230852/comment-autocomplete-reply-in-ios-app)

So if you want the latest version, stay on alpha. If you want the easiest upgrade process, go to the App Store. If you want to help test as much as possible, keep both. But be warned you'll get double notifications. Easy enough to disable one though.

Comment: Oops :) Maybe I'll download the beta again then.

Comment: I've not had any problems with running both apps and controlling notifications on/off for either using the settings app. Other than both apps are named the same, it's pretty easy to manage the notifications if you keep both apps on the same device.

Comment: Bingo. If you want bleeding edge, stay on the beta. If you want automatic updates and stability, get the App Store version.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the beta, download from the App Store, and log back in.

There's no 'cleaner' way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to keep the store version in a folder named "attic" where I place all sorts of apps that aren't the main version I want to run and am running the app signed by SE as an alpha/beta. I have the store version just so I can review it in the store as well as fall back to it in case I need to regression test.

The team is iterating so fast, I'd prefer to use the latest build they are comfortable releasing knowing I can revert to the web interface or store version if needed.

I don't have any notifications on, but there's no problem with choosing to get two sets of notifications or have one or the other app permitted to send push notifications. Just go to settings app and disable notifications for one or both of the apps as you desire. Since they are named the same and have the same icon, just pay attention to which icon is placed where on your screen.

Comment: For me, the app icons and app names are different.