# Reply icon is not showing for comment in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276866/152859), when tapping a comment in the Android app, we should have a reply icon, letting us reply to the comment, instead of the auto complete on the site:

> [image]

However, when I tap a comment I get the "flag" icon instead of reply icon:

> [image]

What is going on? Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Not a bug, and not required. There is a reply icon, which does not exist on the site.

Comment: I'm using v1.0.85 and where the reply button should be according to that other question there is a button to flag the comment instead

Comment: @ShadowWizard Although the interface changes between a showing a reply arrow and a triangle with an exclamation mark in. So it is a bug

Comment: Same version here, I see reply and flag icons when tapping a comment made by someone else, and link to profile and delete when tapping my own comment. Never saw triangle with exclamation mark, can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: That is really weird. What happens when you tap that icon? Is this flagging? What you get when clicking the three vertical dots?

Comment: @ShadowWizard so the option to flag disappears from the three dots menu and is now accessed by the warning triangle. Seems silly that the reply function completely disappeared

Comment: OK, I have rewrote this as a bug report and reopened. As feature request it would just be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.94 going live right now.

Per the release notes:

> The "Reply" button in the action bar when selecting a comment is now usable while already writing a comment

When the commenting UI is visible, the post which you are commenting on doesn't show the "Add Comment" button, since you're already commenting on it. You can see this in the second screenshot in the question vs the first one.

The issue ended up being that we used the same `can_add_comment` variable to control showing both that "Add Comment" button, and the Reply button. When that commenting UI is open, to hide the "Add Comment" button we set `can_add_comment` to false, which then caused the Reply button to disappear too.

As of version 1.0.94, we use a `can_add_comment` variable and a `is_mid_commenting` variable, which lets us hide the "Add Comment" button separately from showing/hiding the Reply button.

It's not perfect, because you can keep on hitting Reply on the same comment over and over again and each time it'll add the `@Username` to the front of your pending comment, but it makes a whole lot more sense than what was happening before.