# Can't vote up comments on Android?

Tags: support, android-app

I usually use my PC to browse stack exchange but I've recently downloaded the android app for more constant accessibility. However on the app when I see a comment that I appreciate and find useful there is no button to up vote it, nor is there a flag option. Am I not looking in the right place or is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Am I not looking in the right place?

1. Tap on the comment to select it.
2. Tap the up arrow on the top bar to upvote it.

   [image]

Note:

The up arrow will only be there if you have joined the site and logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t use the Android app, but you should be able to tap the comment and see a toolbar at the top of the screen. From there you can upvote, reply, and flag. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276866/323179) for more information.

The iOS app works similarly but the menu is under the comment.